# Upper bound for amount of distinct subsets

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I have the following problem. 
Let the sets $A_i$, $1 \leq i \leq k$ be distinct subest of $\{1,2,...,n\}$. Suppose $A_i \cap A_j \neq \emptyset$ for all $i$ and $j$. Show that $k \leq 2^{n-1}$ and give an example where equality holds.

For the first part my argument was the following, we know that we want the sets all to at least one common element, so say they all share element $x$. Now, to form different subsets we can only choose elements from the set $\{1,...,x-1,x+1,...,n\}$. So, this implies that the maximum number of subsets, where all share element $x$ will be $2^{n-1}$. Is this a right approach to the problem?

Also, do you have any suggestions for the second part of the problem?

Comment: No. That demonstrates that we can achieve $k=2^{n-1}$ but you have not shown why all the sets have to have a common element.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assume that $\bigcap_{i=1}^kA_i=\varnothing$. If $n=3$, for instance, the sets might by $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{2,3\}$, and $\{1,2,3\}$, whose intersection is $\varnothing$ even though no two of them are disjoint.

HINT: Suppose that $k>2^{n-1}$, and use the pigeonhole principle. The $2^n$ subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ can be divided up into pairs of complementary subsets, like the pair $\big\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\big\}$ in the case $n=3$. In terms of $n$, how many such pairs are there? Can the family $\{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$ contain both members of any pair?

Your incorrect argument for the first part essentially answers the second part. Let the subsets of $\{2,\ldots,n\}$ be $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_{2^{n-1}}$, and for $i=1,\ldots,2^{n-1}$ let $A_i=\{1\}\cup B_i$. Now just verify that this actually works.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I see my mistake now. Do you know of any books for practicing this kind of problems or reviewing this part of the theory from extremal set theory?

Comment: @Esteban: You’re welcome. I’m afraid that I don’t; I’m largely self-taught in this area and never had occasion to teach it, so I’m not familiar with the books that are out there.

Comment: One nice book with many problems similar to this is "Combinatorial Problems and Exercises" by Lovász.

Comment: @András: I’ve not seen it, but I’m not surprised to hear this: his lecture notes with K. Vesztergombi are very nicely done.